# Correct way to compare two objects extending Comparable

Tags: java, generics, parameters, compare

I'm new to generics and having trouble figuring out how to properly compare two Comparable objects.

```
private int getSortPos(int dir, Comparable d1, Comparable d2) {
    if (d1 == null && d2 != null)
    {
        return dir * -1;
    }
    else if (d1 != null && d2 == null)
    {
        return dir;
    }
    else if (d1 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return dir * d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
}
```

I'm using this code to compare both String and Date objects, both extending Comparable. I'm using sonar in IntelliJ and it tells me: "Provide the parametrized type for this generic" referring to the function parameters. The code works as intended but have "Major code smell". What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Most likely you want `private <T> int getSortPos(int dir, Comparable<T> d1, Comparable<T> d2) { ... }`.

Comment: By the way, `compareTo` doesn't always return -1, 0, or 1. It can return an arbitrary positive/negative number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> int getSortPos(int dir, T d1, T d2) {
    if (d1 == null && d2 != null)
    {
        return dir * -1;
    }
    else if (d1 != null && d2 == null)
    {
        return dir;
    }
    else if (d1 == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return dir * d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
}
```

Doing it this way solved my problem. Is there an even better solution?

Comment: With your logic, you impose a special handling when `d2` is `null`, and that handling may be different from the implementation of `compareTo()` for the given type `T`. That can be correct/desired, but it would at least deserve a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make your objects extends `Comparable<? super T>` . Check Collections API's `sort(List<T>)`, `max(Collection<? extends T> coll)` declarations 
https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java

```
private <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int getSortPos(int dir, T d1, T d2){}
```